# SBS 2008 IIS7 and Linux Apache2 in the same LAN on the same port

Tags: domain-name-system, iis-7, windows-sbs-2008

I have an SBS 2008 with IIS7 on it running a web site "www.domain.com", I also have a Web Server (Linux) with Apache2 in the same LAN running a web site "apps.domain.com".
The problem I have is that all the requests on port 80 from WAN goes straight to the SBS's IIS7, even thou I have specified in the SBS DNS Server that the apps Host(A) is other host than the SBS.

If I browse the "apps.domain.com" from LAN the right server answers, but if I browse from the WAN the same web site "apps.domain.com" it answers the IIS7 from the SBS with the 404 Err.
Is there a way of bypassing the IIS7, when request are made to other hosts that itself?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've only got 1 public ip address (I'm assuming) and as such your router/firewall can only forward traffic coming in to that public ip address to one internal host for port 80. If you want to forward port 80 traffic to the other host you'll need to change the port forwarding on the router/firewall. If you need to forward port 80 to both servers then you'll need two public ip addresses.